# Why is BER higher for binary modulation compared to quaternary?

Tags: signal, modulation, bit-rate

I came across this image in my notes and I fail to understand why [BER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_error_rate) seems to decrease as the modulation order increases and I was hoping for an answer

[image]

Comment: I think you're reading the graph incorrectly - the lower figure is better. So for example at 10dB BPSK is better than 16-PSK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put simply, for the same average energy per bit, the modulation scheme with more bits per symbol must have less distance between the points on its constellation diagram. Therefore a smaller noise excursion can produce a bit error.

Answer (score 4):

That is correct.

The channel with higher bit rate will suffer with a worse BER for the same  SNR  after converting CNR to SNR by demodulation.

Another way to understand this chart is the rise in SNR or Eb/No needed to keep the same BER with higher bandwidth from [Shannon-Hartley Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) [image]

With more compression or bits per baud using more phases per bit, there is a need to increase the energy per bit to noise by a log of this bit ratio.

for \$ BER = 10^{-6}\$
2-PSK  10.5 dB  (BPSK)
4-PSK 14.0 dB
8-PSK 18.5 dB

It appears to be ~ 1dB rise per bit/baud above the baseline for binary PSK at this BER threshold.